# Scrolling (TscrollBar) an OpenGL Control embeded in TPanel

Tags: opengl, c++builder

I develop an application in C++ builder (XE).
I have to dipslay an openGL Component (GLControl for example, which is resizable) in a panel.
I use ScrollBar in this panel to show all composants of OpenGL Component.
So I need to calculate the right page size of TScrollBar and the translation of camera when scrolling panel.

Comment: Why not place the component in a TScrollBox? Then just size the TScrollBox to the size of your component.  You can dynamically resize the TScrollBox using the resize event of the component.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i calculate the pageSize of ScrollBar (having the real height of panel that contain scrollBar and the size drawing) !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i get the solution of my probem.
the equation that calculate the page size of my scrollBar is :

PageSize = ScrollBar->Max * (Height_Panel / Height_Draw);

And be carefull about the position of camera in OpenGl.

Comment: Excellent, no need for me to dig then :-)